# Flutter: Is there a way to handle headphone play/pause media button?

Tags: flutter, bluetooth

For a side-project of mine (think of it as a talkie-walkie replica), I would need to handle to handle the long press of the `mediaPlayPause` button (so that you speak while pressing the button).
I started with a prototype that reads the keyboard input based on the [flutter example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/PhysicalKeyboardKey-class.html), essentially showing the keystroke. (tried with the logical app as well).

But the button (nor vol Up/Down) doesn't show up.

Has anyone been able to capture those external device keys?

Answer (score 1):

You're should take a look at the [audio_service](https://pub.dev/packages/audio_service) plugin. It simplifies the implementation by just extending a unique interface to listen to events like play/pause/next/previous and so on. The basic implementation is as follows:

```dart
class MyAudioHandler extends BaseAudioHandler
    with QueueHandler, // mix in default queue callback implementations
    SeekHandler { // mix in default seek callback implementations
  
  // The most common callbacks:
  Future<void> play() async {
    // All 'play' requests from all origins route to here. Implement this
    // callback to start playing audio appropriate to your app. e.g. music.
  }
  Future<void> pause() async {}
  Future<void> stop() async {}
  Future<void> seek(Duration position) async {}
  Future<void> skipToQueueItem(int i) async {}
}
```

The problem is that [it's not possible to listen for a media button long-press](https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/issues/261) as this action is hard-coded to be something else to the OS itself.

For both [Android MediaButtonReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/media/session/MediaButtonReceiver) and [iOS Remote Control](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uievent/eventsubtype) there is no long-press action to listen to.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll check out the audio service + your implementation.
Really stings to read that it's impossible to listen to long press. Tough one!